# Append a GET variable on to a page with another GET variable

Tags: php

I have a `profile.php` page with a variable `uid?=12` and i have a language bar on that is on a separate page called `lang.inc.php`:

Profile Page:

```
<div class="langbar">
    <?php include 'inc/lang.inc.php'; ?>
</div>
```

lang.inc.php

```
<center>
    <a class="flag_USA" title="English" href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"><img src="css/images/us.png"></a> <span> </span> 
    <a class="flag_France" title="French" href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=fr"><img src="css/images/fr.png"></a> <span> </span> 
    <a class="flag_dutch" title="Dutch"  href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=de"><img src="css/images/de.png"></a> <span> </span> 
    <a class="flag_Italy" title="Italian" href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=it"><img src="css/images/it.png"></a> <span> </span> 
    <a class="flag_Italy" title="" href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=es"><img src="css/images/sp.png"></a> <span> </span> 
    <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
</center>
```

As you can see im trying to append the `?lang=fr` for example to the end of the `profile.php?uid=12` so it looks like this `profile.php?uid=12&lang=fr` but all it's doing is `profile.php?lang=fr`.

Comment: `<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>` OUTPUT ?

Comment: I don't see where are you trying that

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] does not include get variables, just the file path, so you'd have to add the uid to the href yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $basename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // Lets store the basename
    $basename_with_uid = $basename . "?uid=" . $_GET['uid']; // and append the uid from the URL. Make sure to do some validation if $_GET['uid'] exists.
?>



<a class="flag_France" title="French" href="<?php echo $basename_with_uid; ?>&lang=fr"><img src="css/images/fr.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_URI is probably what you are after:

```
<a class="flag_France" title="French" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>&lang=fr"><img src="css/images/fr.png"></a>
```

If your page was profile.php?uid=12, the output should be:

```
profile.php?uid=12&lang=fr
```

Ref: [PHP $_SERVER variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

*edit* You may still need to add basename() around REQUEST_URI, depending on what you are doing